# How to hande nodejs/expressjs gateway timeout by THIRD_PARTY_SERVER?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, proxy, timeout

Getting gateway timeout error for `THIRD_PARTY_SERVER` endpoint.

Please see below for how the request is sent to server.

`BROWSER` -> `PROXY_SERVER` -> `THIRD_PARTY_SERVER`

The Problem i'm facing right now is that there is an endpoint `/api/upload` in `THIRD_PARTY_SERVER`, which is failing by throwing gateway timeout error.

Right now i am just restarting the `PROXY_SERVER` to restore the gateway timeout.

I have tried other possible options, like increasing timeout value to say more than 15 minutes.

But other than restarting the `PROXY_SERVER` no other solution is working.

Is there any other possible solution to let the `/api/upload`  work normally without restarting the `PROXY_SERVER`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.